# Remote Event Receivers are not firing in PHA - onpremises

Tags: event-receivers, csom, remote-event-receiver

We have remote event receivers deployed through PHA in on-premises. For sometime RER is working fine. But suddenly stopped working. I am able to attach or detach event receivers to the lists/libraries. I have checked with below code whether the event receives got attached or not.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "mysiteurl"
$list = $web.Lists["My List"]
$list.EventReceivers | select name, class
```

It is displaying list of event receivers. But remote event receiver is not firing. How I can say remote event receiver is not firing is, at the beginning of event receiver I am logging message to event viewer. But that is also not coming.
Any services or permissions issue?
How to trouble shoot. Same solution is working in dev environment but not in UAT. What could be the reason?

Comment: Network problem between SP and your remote app possibly? Firewall or something

Comment: How I can check that? I am able to load RER url in browser.